# how to redirect the output as well as get the output on shell screen at same time

Tags: c#

This is windows-application-form code; I want the batch file which is going to be executed to show the output on shell screen which I got by `RedirectStandardOutput = false;`, but I also want output to be redirected to a log file at the same time. For this, I use `RedirectStandardOutput = true;`.

Of course, only one can be used at one time!

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\test\build.bat"; 

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 

p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // if I use false all the commented lines below are not applicable for comments

p.Start(); 

string output = null; 
//try 
//{ 

output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 

//} 
//catch (Exception ex) 
//{ 
//    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
//} 

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\test\log.txt", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the output and print it to the screen yourself.  That's how the `tee` command meets this need on most non-Windows operating systems.

Comment: That's not very helpful, he/she is obviously using Windows as they are writing to C:\

Comment: @codemonkeh: Would you consider my first sentence more helpful by itself?  I'm fully aware that we're dealing with Windows here, that's why I didn't say "just use `tee`", but what to do.  The fact that it's a common enough thing to do on command-line oriented systems that POSIX standardized a command is just background information to help convince the OP that this is the right approach.

Comment: I think @system-rule is looking for a specific in-code solution, so they would prefer an example. Sorry if I did offended you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\test\build.bat"; 
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
p.Start();
```

And have an event handler somewhere in your code:

```
private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{   
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
         System.IO.File.AppendAllText("c:\test\log.txt", outLine.Data); 
    }
}
```

Example taken from [MSDN: Process.BeginOutputReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx). It would be more efficient to keep the file open for writing, or even to buffer it but this keeps the example short.

Comment: thanks for your great response i tried this but it dosent call SortOutputHandler and nither create file(logfile) but it gives output on shell screen when i change the this p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false ;  (true -> false)
my problem is still not solved :(

i want something which gives me output on screen as well as i can get that output on a file so that i can maintain a log file...